# How to use regular expression to do a partial replace?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have an email address in Ruby which I need to obfuscate by replacing all characters except the first 3 and the last 3, with asterisks. In other words: if "abcd.ef@example.com" is the input, the output should be "abc*************com"

Ruby has a gsub method which can replaces all occurrences of a pattern with a given string. What regexp should I write that matches all characters which are to be replaced by an asterisk? In other words, a pattern that matches all characters which are NEITHER in the first three NOR in the last three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
email.sub(/\A(...)(.*)(...)\z/) {|m| $1 + ("*" * $2.length) + $3 }
```

1 up vote for the non-regexp solution.

Answer (score 5):

I would do that without regexps:

```
email = 'abcd.ef@example.com'

email[3..-4] = '*' * email[3..-4].length

email # => "abc*************com"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
email.gsub(email[3..-4], "*"*email[3..-4].size)
# => "abc*************com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need exact number of asterisks? If no, you can use this regex:

```
(^.{3})(.*)(.{3}$)
```

> 1. (^.{3}) is first group matching only first three chars
> 2. (.*) matches everythig between boundary groups
> 3. (.{3}$) is ending group mathing last three chars

Knowing that, you can use that regex in replace:

```
$1*****$3
```

> 1. $1 is first matched group (first three chars)
> 2. it's followed by five asterisks
> 3. $3 is third matched group (last three chars)

Try it out yourself: http://www.regexe.com/ and check if it works for you